# How to find rows with max value without aggregate functions SQLPLUS Oracle11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to find rows with max credit on my table ,

```
CREATE TABLE Course(
    CourseNr INTEGER,
    CourseTitel VARCHAR(60),
    CourseTyp VARCHAR(10),
    CourselenghtDECIMAL,
    Credit DECIMAL,
    PRIMARY KEY (CourseNr)
);
```

and there is more than one courses with max value. I dont want to use any default functions for that, any ideas?

Comment: If you don't want to use functions, what do you want to use?

Comment: i meant any default functions like MAX() or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, you want the *rows* with the maximum credit.  A common method is to find any rows that have no larger credit:

```
select c.*
from course c
where c.credit >= all (select c2.credit from course c2);
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer but i dont understand the logic behind that. What do you mean with c.* ? Sorry im a newbie  ^^

Comment: @YasahanZengin . . . That returns all the columns in `course`.  You can list the columns one-by-one if you prefer.

Comment: @YasahanZengin . . . And it was by far the earlier answer.

Answer (score 0):

Get the rows with `Credit` for which there don't exist any rows with greater `Credit`:

```
SELECT 
  c.* 
FROM Course c
WHERE 
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM Course WHERE Credit > c.Credit
  )
```